# DataNode cannot connect with Name Node - "org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server"

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I've deployed a Hadoop 3.1.2 cluster with 1 Namenode and 2 Datanodes. NameNode is UP, secondaryNameNode and ResourceManager also up for Master Node, however DataNode cannot connect with the NameNode, thus no capacity is shown.

I've been trying to find out what the error might be, but haven't succeed so far.

Removed domain resolutions as I was getting odd errors:

```
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as hadoop in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [server]
lim_sbo_bigdata_master: ERROR: Cannot set priority of namenode process 11606
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [server]
lim_sbo_bigdata_master: ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 11825
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers


* SELinux is disabled
* IPtables is OPEN for all traffic:

hadoop@lim_server]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

- Servers belong to the same network.

## NameNode:

```
[hadoop@server ~]$ hadoop version
Hadoop 3.1.2
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r 1019dde65bcf12e05ef48ac71e84550d589e5d9a
Compiled by sunilg on 2019-01-29T01:39Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 64b8bdd4ca6e77cce75a93eb09ab2a9
This command was run using /home/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.2.jar

[hadoop@server ~]$ jps
27089 Jps
26760 ResourceManager
26491 SecondaryNameNode
26239 NameNode

[hadoop@server ~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Replicated Blocks:
    Under replicated blocks: 0
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0
    Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
    Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups: 
    Low redundancy block groups: 0
    Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
    Missing block groups: 0
    Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0

<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
```

## DataNode Error

```
[hadoop@server_2]$ jps
17052 DataNode
17166 NodeManager
17406 Jps

2019-08-27 05:46:09,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 9867
2019-08-27 05:46:09,229 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened IPC server at /0.0.0.0:9867
2019-08-27 05:46:09,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Refresh request received for nameservices: null
2019-08-27 05:46:09,251 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting BPOfferServices for nameservices: <default>
2019-08-27 05:46:09,260 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to /10.30.17.228:9000 starting to offer serv
ice
2019-08-27 05:46:09,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2019-08-27 05:46:09,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 9867: starting
2019-08-27 05:46:10,330 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 10.30.17.228/10.30.17.228:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountW
ithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2019-08-27 05:46:11,331 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 10.30.17.228/10.30.17.228:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountW
ithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "localhost" to the actual hostname or IP of the namenodes.

Comment: When I do that, I get the following errors:
lim_server: ERROR: Cannot set priority of namenode process 11606
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [server]
lim_server: ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 11825
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers

Comment: See if this is the issue you are having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283634/localhost-error-cannot-set-priority-of-datanode-process-32156

Comment: Also might be good to share your hdfs-site and hadoop-env configurations

Comment: Hello guys, I solved the issue using the IP address for the hdfs-site.xml file, change mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml properly.

Comment: @MarcoGonzalezOrtiz, I am stuck with the same issue, so can you please elaborate on how these new *-site.xml files look like in all 3 nodes?