# Hadoop: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am very new to hadoop and am trying to set a psuedo-distributed mode execution with Hadoop-3.1.2.
When I try to start yarn service I get the following error, please see the code snippet below.

```
$ sbin/start-yarn.sh 
Starting resourcemanagers on []
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process 13209
pdsh@manager-4: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of nodemanager process 13366
pdsh@manager-4: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1
```

I tried solutions at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283634/localhost-error-cannot-set-priority-of-datanode-process-32156) stackoverflow question, which is very similar to my problem. But nothing worked out. A problem same as mine is posted in another forum [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/486770/resource-manager-is-not-starting-on-both-master-an/). However, no solution is available there as well.

Then, I tried another option which I am describing in the following text.
I set following *exports* in the file *sbin/start-yarn.sh*.

```
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER="root"
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER="root"
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER="root"
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER="root"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER="root"
```

Then executed with *sbin/start-yarn.sh* and I got the following error. Please note that I have done all the settings for passwordless ssh for root@localhost.

```
$ sudo sbin/start-yarn.sh
Starting resourcemanagers on []
localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
pdsh@manager-4: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 255
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
pdsh@manager-4: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 255
```

Comment: are you running the script under non-root user?  the prompt char in your first command does not look right . run command ```id -a``` to confirm .

Comment: @bigdataolddriver In the first case I am not. In the second case (i.e. after exporting users as root) I am running with sudo. Please see the updated execution command in the question.

Comment: @bigdataolddriver Thanks. When I tried 'sudo -i -u root sbin/start-yarn.sh' I get following error: '-bash: sbin/start-yarn.sh: No such file or directory'. Then I switched user by running 'sudo su' and then executed 'sbin/start-yarn.sh'. I got the same error as 'ssh exited with exit code 255'

Comment: @bigdataolddriver I tried this as well: 'sudo -i -u root /home/uname/Hadoop/hadoop-3.1.2/sbin/start-yarn.sh' and got the same exit with 255 error.

Comment: sorry I did not consider the side  effect of $HOME dir switching.  as i am not sure about the ssh auth priority under sudo command line . if you still want to running command as non-root ,  could  you  try  ```bash -x sbin/start-yarn.sh``` and update with the output ?  the output can help me understand why is it throwing error.

Comment: @bigdataolddriver The output when executed with bash -x is very huge. Cannot be sent in comment. Shall I email you?

Comment: @bigdataolddriver sent messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the steps suggested by zhao, ephraimbuddy and qitian.
Please make sure that if you have a firewall running than the firewall is not blocking it in anyway. Also make sure that the user with which you are executing the command has enough permissions to update the priorities.

Answer (score 2):

I had  the same issue, what helped me was the guide I found in this [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-issues/201905.mbox/%3CJIRA.13232506.1557423975000.225981.1557424020058@Atlassian.JIRA%3E)!

The message "Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process" is misleading. I checked the resource manager logs and found that there was an error as follows

```
Unexpected close tag </property>; expected </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was finally able to solve it. I got ResourceManager and NodeManager to run. If you're running Hadoop 3.3 and up, the issue might be with the java version you're using. [hadoop_compatibility](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions)

> > " Apache Hadoop 3.3 and upper supports Java 8 and Java 11 (runtime only)
> > Please compile Hadoop with Java 8. Compiling Hadoop with Java 11 is not supported"

Solution:

- Try switching to java 8.
- Then make sure your JAVA_HOME path variables are pointing to java 8 (including any JAVA_HOME path variables in hadoop-env.sh).
- If the issue persists, check the error messages in resourcemanager log located in $HADOOP_HOME/logs/.

Answer (score 1):

Before running the start-yarn script, try the command: ssh localhost

Answer (score 1):

When you have set passwordless ssh for localhost change the pdsh_rcmd_type value to ssh:

```
export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh
```

Answer (score 1):

this error info actually very confuse me, later i find it happens because i have not correctly config cgroup. so you can firstly check your config make sure they are all right, you can check you resourcemanager logs