# ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 16536 (datanode and namenode Deamons not running)

Tags: hadoop, installation, hadoop-plugins

This is the output of my terminal:
[image]

The errors showing up are the following:

```
ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 16536 
ERROR: Cannot set priority of namenode process 16556
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 32156](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283634/localhost-error-cannot-set-priority-of-datanode-process-32156)

Comment: make sure you have configured it correctly. Check JAVA to be in version 8, otherwise it may act up. Now if you made a new user, so you have to give it access to sudo or make it sudoer(search it). Then if not works put everything from the first configuration till end so that we can help you.