# "ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 31231"

Tags: macos, hadoop, homebrew, namenode

I have a problem with Hadoop. I am on mac OS and I have a problem when I want to launch my node.
I installed Hadoop this way :

```
brew install hadoop
```

I also configured the different files like this :

hadoop-env.sh :

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

core-site.xml :

```
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. --><configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories</description>             
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml :

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml :

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I finally executed this command:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

Finally when I want to launch the command ./start-dfs.sh I get this error :

"*ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 31231*"

I would like to specify that my main node launches correctly :

[image]

I can't find a solution on the internet.
Has anyone faced the same situation as me?

I tried all the solutions but doesn't work : [localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 32156](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283634/localhost-error-cannot-set-priority-of-datanode-process-32156)

Sincerely,

Comment: Look at the log file created, not terminal output. Try downgrading to Java 11. Also, `mapreduce.framework.name` needs to be `yarn`. Seems like you copied something wrong

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't find the log file... but I downgrade to Java 11 et change to yarn but nothing change. I had the same error...

Answer (score 0):

For people who had the same problems as me, here is a tuto that might work:
:https://techblost.com/how-to-install-hadoop-on-mac-with-homebrew/